# How do I convert 2d arrays to 2 arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

1 - I need to store 2d arrays as 2 arrays – title and author. Is there a way to store each author’s name as a string just once?

Every line of code is mine, I am just trying to rework this to look simplier. The entire code is functional and I am just asking for help to convert the 2d arrays to 2 arrays without breaking the entire thing. And yes, this is an university assignment which I am asking how to convert 2d arrays. I am not asking you to do the assigment for me in any way as If I wanted I could easily submit this and get a a 80%. –

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UofSarrePublishing
{
    public partial class EPOS : Form
    {
        /*Definition of constants for Distributors,Titles and Authors.*/

        const int Authors = 3;
        const int Distributors = 3;
        const int Titles = 5;


        /*Definition of arrays.*/

        static string[,] books = new string[Titles, 2]; //Array containing books and their authors.//
        static double[] prices = { 6.47, 0.99, 29.14, 10.50, 319.56 }; //Price of each book title.//
        static int[] stock = new int[Titles];
        static int[,] sales = new int[Titles,Distributors]; //Sales for book title by distributor.//


        /*Array for distributors.*/

        static int[] basket = new int[5]; //Current basket.//
        static string[] distributors = { "University of Sarre Bookshop", "Amaze-oon.co.uk", "Earthmarble Bookshops" };
        private int a;

        /*Function is prompted at the beggining to fill in books,authors and stock.*/

        void insertData()
        {
            books[0, 0] = "1000 Best Jokes on Milling and Grinding";
            books[1, 0] = "10000 Awful Jokes on Milling and Grinding";
            books[2, 0] = "Civet Cat Husbandry in the UK";
            books[3, 0] = "When Milling goes wrong: stories of death in Milling";
            books[4, 0] = "Everything you ever wanted to know about mill construction... and then some: The world's biggest bumper book of mill construction";
            books[0, 1] = "S Presso";
            books[1, 1] = "S Presso";
            books[2, 1] = "S Presso";
            books[3, 1] = "Win D Power";
            books[4, 1] = "Dr Footing";

            stock[0] = 8;
            stock[1] = 3238;
            stock[2] = 3;
            stock[3] = 37;
            stock[4] = 2;

            /*Writes stock in the textboxes.*/

            uiStockCatTextBox.Text = "3";
            uiStockWhenTextBox.Text = "37";
            uiStockEverythingTextBox.Text = "2";
            uiStock10000TextBox.Text = "3238";
            uiStock1000TextBox.Text = "8";

        }

        /*Function to retrieve values from the basket (textboxes).*/

        void getBasket()
        {
            /* Parse string into integer and save into basket array.*/

            basket[0] += int.Parse(uiBasket1000TextBox.Text);
            basket[1] += int.Parse(uiBasket10000TextBox.Text);
            basket[2] += int.Parse(uiBasketCatTextBox.Text);
            basket[3] += int.Parse(uiBasketWhenTextBox.Text);
            basket[4] += int.Parse(uiBasketEverythingTextBox.Text);

        }

        /*Function to remove items from basket.*/

        void emptyBasket()
        {
            /*Zero elements of basket array.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < basket.Length; a++)
            {
                basket[a] = 0;
            }

        }

        /*Function to reset basket's values.*/

        void resetBasket()
        {
            uiBasketCatTextBox.Text = "0";
            uiBasketEverythingTextBox.Text = "0";
            uiBasketWhenTextBox.Text = "0";
            uiBasket1000TextBox.Text = "0";
            uiBasket10000TextBox.Text = "0";

            emptyBasket();
        }

        /*Function that creates a new sale by checking/getting customer's basket.*/

        void createSale(int id)
        {
            /*Get values of the basket - Defines total price.*/

            getBasket();

            double totalPrice = 0;
            int totalItems = 0;


            /*Summary of price/sum of item values in the basket.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < Titles; a++)
            {
                totalPrice += prices[a] * basket[a];
                totalItems = totalItems + basket[a];
            }

            /*Check if stock is available to proceed sale.
             In case of no stock an error message is displayed.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < stock.Length; a++)
            {
                /*Check if there is enough stock.*/

                if (stock[a]- basket[a] < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "Out of stock. Order can't be completed!",
                    "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                    MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);

                    /*Removes items from the basket and cancels sale.*/

                    emptyBasket();
                    return;

                }
            }

            /*Proceeds with sale if enough stock.*/

            string message = "The total price is £" + totalPrice.ToString("F")+". Proceed?";
            string caption = "Sale confirmation";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, message, caption, buttons,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
            MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);

            /*If user clicks buttom "OK" sale will be stored in the sale array and stock is updated.*/

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < Titles; a++)
                {
                    sales[a, id] += basket[a];
                }
                updateStock();
                uiStock1000TextBox.Text = stock[0].ToString();
                uiStock10000TextBox.Text = stock[1].ToString();
                uiStockCatTextBox.Text = stock[2].ToString();
                uiStockWhenTextBox.Text = stock[3].ToString();
                uiStockEverythingTextBox.Text = stock[4].ToString();

                /*Resets basket and starts a new sale.*/

                resetBasket();
            }
            else
            {
                emptyBasket();
            }


        }

        /*This function updates stock after a sale is succesfully completed.*/

        void updateStock()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < stock.Length; a++)
            {
                stock[a] -= basket[a];
            }

        }

        /*Entry point*/

        public EPOS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            insertData();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /*Function is prompted when "Sale" button is clicked.
        It checks for a valid Customer ID - In case of error, a message is shown.*/

        private void uiSaleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tmp = uiCustomerNumberTextBox.Text;
            if ( tmp== "" || int.Parse(tmp)-1>2 || int.Parse(tmp)-1<0)
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Please enter a valid Customer ID (enter 1=University of Sarre Bookshop, 2=Amaze-oon.co.uk, 3=Earthmarble Bookshop)",
                    "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                    MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
            else
            {
                /*A valid Customer ID equals to 1,2 and 3 //
                It substracts 1 to get 0,1,2.*/

                int id = int.Parse(tmp)-1;
                createSale(id);
            }
        }

        /*Function to show a report of total sales per Author.
        (Bubble sort is used).*/

        private void uiAuthorChartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*2D array that stores sales per author.*/

            string[,] salesPerAuthor = new string[3,2];
            salesPerAuthor[0,0]= "S Presso";
            salesPerAuthor[1, 0] = "Win D Power";
            salesPerAuthor[2, 0] = "Dr Footing";

            /*Resets previous text from the textbox.*/

            uiAuthorChartTextBox.Clear();
            for (int a = 0; a < Authors; a++)
            {
                /*Temporary variable that stores total sales.*/

                int tmp = 0;

                for (int b = 0; b < Titles; b++)
                {
                    /*Find the correct author for specific book.*/

                    if (salesPerAuthor[a,0] != books[b, 1])
                        continue;

                    for (int c = 0; c < Distributors; c++)
                    {
                        /*Calculates total sales of distributors.*/

                        tmp+= sales[b, c];

                    }

                }
                /*Store the total sales to array.*/

                salesPerAuthor[a, 1] = tmp.ToString();
                tmp = 0;

            }

            /*Sorts sales per author in ascending order.*/

            bubbleSort(salesPerAuthor);

            /*Print total sales per Author in textbox.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < salesPerAuthor.GetLength(0); a++)
            {
                uiAuthorChartTextBox.AppendText(salesPerAuthor[a, 0] + " ---> Total Sales:" + salesPerAuthor[a, 1] + "\n");

            }

            uiAuthorChartTextBox.AppendText("\n");
        }

        /*Bubble sort algorithm that sorts sales per author*/

        private void bubbleSort(string[,] salesPerAuthor)
        {
            bool swap;

            /*Iterates the salerperAuthor array and swaps elements.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < salesPerAuthor.GetLength(0) - 1; a++)
            {
                swap = false;
                for (int b = salesPerAuthor.GetLength(0) - 2; b >= a; b--)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(salesPerAuthor[b, 1]) > int.Parse(salesPerAuthor[b+1, 1]))
                    {
                        /*Swaps both names and number of sales for the specified author.*/

                        int tempNum = int.Parse(salesPerAuthor[b, 1]);
                        salesPerAuthor[b, 1] = salesPerAuthor[b + 1, 1];
                        salesPerAuthor[b + 1, 1] = tempNum.ToString();
                        swap = true;
                        string tmpName = salesPerAuthor[b, 0];
                        salesPerAuthor[b, 0] = salesPerAuthor[b + 1, 0];
                        salesPerAuthor[b + 1, 0] = tmpName;

                    }
                }
                /*If there is no swaps it breaks the loop.*/

                if (!swap)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /*Function to show a report of total sales per Distributor.*/

        private void uiDealerChartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Clears the textbox when button is clicked.*/

            uiDealerChartTextBox.Clear();

            /*Iterates distributors to print total sales for each distributor.*/

            for (int a = 0; a < Distributors; a++)
            {
                uiDealerChartTextBox.AppendText(distributors[a] + "\n");
                for (int b = 0; b < Titles; b++) {
                    uiDealerChartTextBox.AppendText(books[b,0]+" ---> Sales:");
                    uiDealerChartTextBox.AppendText(sales[b,a].ToString() + "\n");

                }
                uiDealerChartTextBox.AppendText("\n");

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Every line of code is mine, I am just trying to rework this to look simplier.
The entire code is functional and I am just asking for help to convert the 2d arrays to 2 arrays without breaking the entire thing.
And yes, this is an university assignment which I am asking how to convert 2d arrays.
I am not asking you to do the assigment for me in any way as If I wanted I could easily submit this and get a a 80%.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes to model your entities and to group the properties. Example:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Authors { get; } = new List<string>();
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Something like this (I'm not sure how your model is). Then you can create a `List<Book>` for the books and don't have keep several array in parallel. Also, a `List<T>` can grow as needed, where an array has a fixed length.

You can also extend the model to have an author class. Then you can reference the same author object in several books

```
public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Born { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Died { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; } = new List<Author>();
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Example

```
var author = new Author {
    Name = "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    Born = new DateTime(1859, 5, 22),
    Died = new DateTime(1930, 7, 7)
};

var books = new List<Book>();

var book = new Book {
     Title = "The Final Problem",
     Price = 10.50m
};
book.Authors.Add(author);
books.Add(book);

var book = new Book {
     Title = "The Adventure of the Empty House",
     Price = 11.20m
};
book.Authors.Add(author); // Adds the same author as in the previous book. Note that a class is
                          // a reference type. I.e., this is not a copy of the author. It is
                          // a reference to the same and unique A. C. Doyle `Author` object.
books.Add(book);

var book = new Book {
     Title = "Hilda Wade",
     Price = 8.75m
};
book.Authors.Add(author);
book.Authors.Add(new Author {
    Name = "Grant Allen",
    Born = new DateTime(1848, 2, 24),
    Died = new DateTime(1899, 10, 25)
}); // A co-author.
books.Add(book);
```

Now you can access information like this

```
foreach (Book b in books) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Book \"{b.Title}\" (£ {b.Price:n2})");
    foreach (Author a in b.Authors) {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {a.Name} *{a.Born}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i get where you are coming from.
In your opnion which one looks more organized? 2d arrays or 2 arrays?

Comment: Arrays are not appropriate. If you have 2 arrays one for titles and one for authors of the book, you have information bits in two collections. If you use a 2d array, you must know which bit of information is at which index. Also all properties stored like this must be strings. You cannot add a third property as `int` as an example. Where as with a list of a book class, you can add any properties of different types belonging to the book. And you have one single list of books containing all the information related to books. And the list grows automatically as you add books.